# Jackson JSON check values before adding them to list

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

Code snippet:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                this.persons = objectMapper.readValue(new File(fileName),
                        new TypeReference<List<Person>>() {
                });
            } catch (IOException ex) {

            }
```

Example json input:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Best",
    "email": "thenextbigthing@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1981-11-23"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Andy Jr.",
    "email": "usa@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1982-12-01"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "JohnDoe",
    "email": "gameover@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1990-01-02"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "SomeOne",
    "email": "rucksack@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1988-01-22"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Mr. Mxyzptlk",
    "email": "bigman@hotmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1977-08-12"
  }
]
```

I'd like to know if it's possible (then how?) to check the values before creating an object and add it to the list. For example, i don't want the object being created and added to the list if the e-mail address or name is longer than 30 characters or if name matches certain regex expression etc. Instead I want to throw an IOException with something like "wrong input data". I'm not allowed to create more custom classes.

Comment: If you are using DTO, you can put on the set method your rule. This is my suggestion.

Comment: Jackson is meant for JSON parsing and not for validation.

Comment: What if I want to check the last object added to the list then stop the parsing if something is wrong?

Comment: See my answer/suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can't do this, because Jackson works on parsing, not for validation.
My suggestion:

```
public boolean checkJson(String jsonStr, Class<?> valueType) throws JsonParseException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        List<TypeHere> list = mapper.readValue(jsonStr, valueType);
        return list.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.length() < 30);
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Instead return a boolean value, you can throw a Exception.

Obs: I'm working on my English yet. Please, feel free to edit.